# How do I call a function from within an external class?

Tags: python, scripting, error

I wrote a code that works fine when I copy and paste it into the scripting area of Blender. Now that I've made an addon out of the same code though, I'm getting errors. I believe one of the errors is due to the way I'm calling the function in an external class. Is there a different way of calling it while avoiding the error?

The error looks something like this (I've modified it to correspond with the code snippet below):

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Blender/3.5/scripts/addons/test.py", line 119, in execute
    bpy.ops.object.my_external_class('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.5/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 111, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
```

I also tried using EXEC_DEFAULT but it provided a similar error message.

Here's the simplified code:

````
class myCallingClass(bpy.types.Operator):
    """My calling class"""
    bl_idname = "object.my_calling_class"
    bl_label = "Calling test"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.my_external_class('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        return {'FINISHED'}

class myExternalClass(bpy.types.Operator):
    """My external class"""
    bl_idname = "object.my_external_class"
    bl_label = "External test"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("ok")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```
````

Comment: Most likely you've not registered `myExternalClass`.

Comment: No it's definitely registered properly but thanks.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, so maybe something that is not shown in your question is the cause of this error.